# Having a duplicate number sequence in slug using FriendlyId

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-id

I'm using the `gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.0.0` and I just want to use the old behaviour which is appending a number sequence count in the slug instead of `UUID`.

for example

```
>> test-slug-2
>> test-slug-3
>> test-slug-4
```

I was able to make this using:
**config/initializers/slugged.rb**

```
module FriendlyId::Slugged
  def resolve_friendly_id_conflict(candidates)
    column = friendly_id_config.slug_column
    separator = friendly_id_config.sequence_separator
    slug = normalize_friendly_id(candidates.first)
    sequence = self.class.where("#{column} like '#{slug}#{separator}%'").count + 2
    "#{slug}#{separator}#{sequence}"
  end
end
```

and in my **model**

```
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]
```

However when I have a `test-slug-3` and `test-slug-4` and tried to delete the `test-slug-3` the next time I create a record it will generate a slug which is `test-slug-4` which is having an error in my end because 
Slug is already taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use the substring method to find the max number.  For example, in PostgreSQL you could do something like:

```
slug_start = "#{slug}#{separator}"
sequence = self.class.where("#{column} like '#{slug_start}%'").maximum("SUBSTR(#{column}, #{slug_start.length + 1})::Int") + 1
```

Comment: Thanks @cschroed  however I'm using mysql my workaround for this is getting the maximum id of the similar slug and add +1 and appends the the slug that will be created.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway I make a workaround for this. 
If slug is already taken the next time you create a slug it will get the maximum id of the similar slug and add +1 and appends to the next slug you will create.

Here's my code:

```
 def resolve_friendly_id_conflict(candidates)
    column = friendly_id_config.slug_column
    separator = friendly_id_config.sequence_separator
    slug = normalize_friendly_id(candidates.first)
    count = self.class.maximum("id") + 1 || 1
    if self.class.where("#{column} like '#{slug}%'").count >= 1
      "#{slug}#{separator}#{count}"
    end
  end
```